# Connecting to Sql Server 2008 R2 using RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connecting my ROR application with Sql Server 2008 but unfortunately I am unable to connection to by database when i try to run the command

rake db:migrate.
its says rake aborted couldn't get .. could not load 'active_record/connection_adapter/sqlserver_adapter'.

I have installed the gem for sql server using the following command
C:\Users\Hamad\RubymineProjects\muslic_library>gem install activerecord-sqlserve
r-adapter
It installs everything successfully but after the installation when i run the command
C:\Users\Hamad\RubymineProjects\muslic_library>rake db:migrate
then the error still appears.
rake db:migrate.
its says rake aborted couldn't get .. could not load 'active_record/connection_adapter/sqlserver_adapter'.

Please guide me if there is something i am missing or i need to install.

**note** The configuration settings for the connection to sql server are under the following
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: music_library_development
  username: sa
  password: *****
  host: 127.0.0.1 #tried localhost/computername as well.

Comment: Did you restart your rails server `rails s` after installing the gem?

Comment: starting the webrick server didn't work out for me. :(

Comment: Can you post your `tiny_tds` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gems version.

Comment: tiny_tds (0.6.1 x86-mingw32) activerecord (4.0.1, 3.2.15). This means that i have two active record gems which can conflict which i have read on the stackoverflow's question. I have uninstall the gem for active record 3.2.15 and tried rake db:migrate but still no luck.

Comment: Try `bundle clean --force` then `bundle install` from your rails root directory.  Then check to make sure that you have expected activerecord version by running `bundle show activerecord`.  You didn't include `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem's version.  Note that you need all three `activerecord`, `tiny_tds`, and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` for this to work.

Comment: activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.12) for sql server

Comment: Vinod I followed your steps but still no luck brother.

Comment: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter'. Make sure
that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other th
an 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to
 the Gemfile.
C:/Users/Hamad/RubymineProjects/muslic_library/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top
(required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Could you add your database.yml file to the question.

Comment: development:  
  host: 127.0.0.1 #have also tried "localhost", localhost,ComputerName
  username: "sa"
  password: "****"
  database: "music_library"
  adapter: "sqlserver"
  #pool: 5
  #timeout: 5000

Comment: Uninstalling the Rails 4.0.1 gem and its dependencies and reinstalling Rails 3.2.12 worked out for me finally.